# ng datepicker displays calender incorrectly saturday let empty

Tags: datepicker, angular2-forms, angular-forms, angular4-forms, angular-date-format

I am using ng datepicker to pick date in my application. Below code displays correct calendar in chrome but not in IE and firefox. Please view the below image and pour in your experiences and suggestions. Currently our customer is live and this is causing major issues.

```
<ng-datepicker formControlName="Date"></ng-datepicker>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moved from ng-datepicker to material datepicker to fix this issue.